# TS object declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript, singleton

I'm new to typescript and javascript, and I want to convert this code in `JS` to its `TS` version. When I try to access `this` object in the typescript version, it says that `'this possibly be 'unknown'` or something like that.
Could you please help me to understand how you implement this code in `TS`?

```
const singleton = {

    instance: null, // socket.io instance

    getInstance: (server) => {
        if (!this.instance) {
            this.instance = server; // takes 'Hello' as the value
        }
        return this.instance;
    },

}

let a = singleton.getInstance('Hello');
let b = singleton.getInstance('World');

console.log(a === b); // true
console.log(a); // Hello
console.log(b); // Hello
```

Comment: Try rewrite function from arrow notation to usual.

Comment: Thanks, its works but why? An arrow function is an object by itself?

Comment: It works because arrow functions as an object property have no reference of this, they have no binding by default. Still you could get it work if you'd use `let a = singleton.getInstance.call(singleton, 'Hello');` More about it you can learn from [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/differences-between-arrow-and-regular-functions/)

Comment: It is all about `function context` :)

Comment: Good you're converting this to Typescript - you just got the compiler find a bug in your Javascript implementation!

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Arrow functions as object methods do not inherit `prototype` reference in `this`. In order to access `prototype` of the object using `this` you need to use ES3 style function (`function () {}`) or simply `{ myFunc() {} }` when inside object literal or class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
class Singleton {

    static instance = null; // socket.io instance

    static getInstance(server) {
        if (!Singleton.instance) {
            Singleton.instance = server; // takes 'Hello' as the value
        }

        return Singleton.instance;
    }

}

let a = Singleton.getInstance('Hello');
let b = Singleton.getInstance('World');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted an object, not a class.

Comment: No, do not use a `class` with only static methods.

Comment: @Bergi My guess is that this is just an example of the code and Ali will add an implementation of it later. Otherwise, it can be just a simple function that keeps an instance encapsulated in const.

I think keeping singleton inside an object is useless.

Comment: @okarp Yes, it should just be a simple function, and I agree that singletons are mostly useless in general :-) (What's worse though is that if `getInstance` takes the instance as a parameter, it isn't even a singleton pattern)